How to create a clickable stepper
I am looking for a solution to create a dynamic stepper.
If I select Heudebouville and then feedbackDo, all the checkboxes between should be checked; that's good for the moment, but if I want to deselect one of the checkboxes between (for example: Babille) it should be deselected (checked=false without changing the classNames), but it's not the case here.
In the example below, I checked the first checkbox and another one, the checkboxes between are checked (it's good) but when I try to deselect them (Post a contest or Provide feedback) they are still checked.

I really hope it's clear.
Here's my code:


  // Switch cites
  $("#fluxLibreSwitchCity").click(function () {
    var fromCity = $(".FluxLibreStep2__From .FluxLibreStep2__City");
    var toCity = $(".FluxLibreStep2__To .FluxLibreStep2__City");

    // Inverse  cities
    var tempCity = fromCity.text();
    fromCity.text(toCity.text());
    toCity.text(tempCity);

    // Inverse passages
    var passages = $(".StepProgress > li");
    var reversedPassages = passages.toArray().reverse();
    $(".StepProgress").html(reversedPassages);
    $(".StepProgress").toggleClass("inverse");
    redrawSteps();
    CalculatePrice();
  });

  // Road
  // Calculate prices
  const CalculatePrice = () => {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
      var totalPrice = 0;
      $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
        var price = parseFloat(
          $(this).siblings("label").find(".infoORprice").text().trim()
        );
        totalPrice += price;
      });
      $("#totalPrice").text(totalPrice.toFixed(2) + " €");
    });
  };
  CalculatePrice();

  // order checkbox
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(
    '.StepProgress-item input[type="checkbox"]'
  );

  checkboxes.forEach((checkbox, index) => {
    checkbox.addEventListener("change", function () {
      redrawSteps();
    });
  });
  const redrawSteps = () => {
    const bluePath = document.querySelectorAll(".StepProgress-item");
    bluePath.forEach((li) => li.classList.remove("is-active"));

    const checked = document.querySelectorAll(
      '.StepProgress-item input[type="checkbox"]:checked'
    );

    if (checked.length > 1) {
      const first = checked[0].closest("li");
      const last = checked[checked.length - 1].closest("li");
      let started = false;
      let finished = false;

      bluePath.forEach((li) => {
        if (li === first) {
          started = true;
        } else if (li === last) {
          finished = true;
        }

        if (started && !finished) {
          const checkbox = li.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
          li.classList.add("is-active");
          if (checkbox && !li.classList.contains("subItem")) {
            checkbox.checked = true;
          }
        }
      });
    }
    var allItems = document.querySelectorAll(".StepProgress-item");
    allItems.forEach(function (item) {
      var checkbox = item.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
      if (checkbox && checkbox.checked) {
        item.classList.add("selected");
      } else {
        item.classList.remove("selected");
      }
    });
  };
.StepProgress {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
.StepProgress:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: calc(100% - 90px);
  border-left: 4px solid gray;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
}
.StepProgress__FromToCity {
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: gray;
  margin-left: -6px !important;
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}
.StepProgress__FromToCity:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='18' height='18' viewBox='0 0 18 18' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M15 7.5c0 4.5-6 9-6 9s-6-4.5-6-9a6 6 0 1 1 12 0' stroke='%23787878' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/%3E%3Cpath d='M9 9.75a2.25 2.25 0 1 0 0-4.5 2.25 2.25 0 0 0 0 4.5' stroke='%23787878' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}
.StepProgress__FromToCity:last-child {
  margin-top: -10px;
}
.StepProgress-item {
  position: relative;
  display: flex !important;
  padding-bottom: 20px !important;
  height: 100px;
}
.StepProgress-item input[type="checkbox"] {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
  left: -8px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.StepProgress-item input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  box-shadow: 0px 9px 17px -4px gray;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.StepProgress-item input[type="checkbox"]:checked:before {
  content: "";
  background-color: blue;
}
.StepProgress-item input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #e0f8ff;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.StepProgress-item input[type="checkbox"]:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.StepProgress-item__subItemPassageNum {
  display: contents;
}
.StepProgress-item__InfoPassage {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.StepProgress-item__InfoPassage span {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.StepProgress-item__InfoPassage .infoORprice {
  color: gray;
}
.StepProgress-item__InfoPassage .icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.6);
  align-self: baseline;
  padding: 2px 3px;
}
.StepProgress-item__InfoPassage .icon::before {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.StepProgress-item.selected > * {
  z-index: 1;
}
.StepProgress-item.selected:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #f4f4f499;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  width: calc(100% + 10px);
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 10px);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
.StepProgress-item.subItem {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
.StepProgress-item.subItem.selected > * {
  z-index: 1;
}
.StepProgress-item.subItem.selected:after {
  content: "";
  left: -40px;
  width: calc(100% + 50px);
}
.StepProgress-item.subItem input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  box-shadow: 0px 9px 17px -4px gray;
}
.StepProgress-item.subItem input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .StepProgress-item__InfoPassage:before {
  background-color: blue;
  left: -67px;
  width: 30px;
}
.StepProgress-item.subItem .StepProgress-item__InfoPassage {
  position: relative;
}
.StepProgress-item.subItem .StepProgress-item__InfoPassage:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -70px;
  top: 16px;
  width: 34px;
  height: 4px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: gray0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.StepProgress-item.subItem.is-active {
  position: relative;
}
.StepProgress-item.subItem.is-active:before {
  content: "";
  left: -40px;
  top: 14px;
  height: 100%;
}
.StepProgress-item.not-active * {
  color: #787878;
}
.StepProgress-item.not-active input[type="checkbox"]::before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.StepProgress-item.not-active .StepProgress-item__InfoPassage + span {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
.StepProgress-item:last-of-type {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.StepProgress-item.is-active:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  height: calc(100% - 8px);
  width: 4px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 2;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="FluxLibreStep2" id="step2">
                            <button class="FluxLibre__IconBackStep" id="returnToPreviousStep"></button>

                            <div class="FluxLibreStep2__top">
                                 

                                <div class="FluxLibreStep2__FromTo">
                                    <div class="FluxLibreStep2__From">
                                        <span>De</span>
                                        <div class="FluxLibreStep2__City">
                                            Paris </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="button" class="FluxLibre__IconSwitch" id="fluxLibreSwitchCity"></button>
                                    <div class="FluxLibreStep2__To">
                                        <span>Vers</span>
                                        <div class="FluxLibreStep2__City">
                                            Caen</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="FluxLibreStep2__Road">
                                <ul class="StepProgress list-inline">
                                    <li class="StepProgress__FromToCity">
                                        Paris
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="StepProgress-item">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="point1" name="passage" value="point1">
                                        <label for="point1" class="StepProgress-item__InfoPassage">
                                            Heudebouville
                                            <span class="infoORprice">
                                                12 €</span>
                                            <span class="icon icon-{{ iconPassage }}" aria-hidden="true">A10</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="StepProgress-item subItem">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="point2" name="passage" value="point2">
                                        <label for="point2" class="StepProgress-item__InfoPassage">
                                            Montreuil
                                            <span class="StepProgress-item__subItemPassageNum">(n°6a)</span>
                                            <span class="infoORprice">
                                                12 €</span>
                                            <span class="icon icon-{{ iconSousPassage  }}" aria-hidden="true">A11</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                     
                                    <li class="StepProgress-item">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="point4" name="passage" value="point4">
                                        <label for="point4" class="StepProgress-item__InfoPassage">
                                            Babille
                                            <span class="infoORprice">
                                                12 €</span>

                                            <span class="icon icon-{{ iconPassage }}" aria-hidden="true">A12</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="StepProgress-item subItem not-active">
                                        <input disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" id="point5" name="passage" value="point5">
                                        <label for="point5" class="StepProgress-item__InfoPassage">
                                            Handover
                                            <span class="infoORprice">
                                                Ouverture du portic flux libre le 25/12/2024
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="icon icon-{{ iconSousPassage }}" aria-hidden="true">A13</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="StepProgress-item">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="point6" name="passage" value="point6">
                                        <label for="point6" class="StepProgress-item__InfoPassage">
                                            Provide
                                            <span class="StepProgress-item__subItem-PassageNum">
                                                (n°6a)
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="infoORprice">
                                                6 €
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="icon icon-{{ iconPassage }}" aria-hidden="true">A51</label>
                                        </li>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="StepProgress-item subItem">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="point7" name="passage" value="point7">
                                        <label for="point7" class="StepProgress-item__InfoPassage">
                                             feedbackDo
                                            <span class="StepProgress-item__subItem-PassageNum">
                                                (n°6a)
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="infoORprice">
                                                6 €
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="icon icon-{{ iconPassage }}" aria-hidden="true">A51</label>
                                        </li>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="StepProgress__FromToCity">
                                        Caen
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <p>Selected option:
                                <span id="selectedOption"></span>
                            </p>

                            <div class="FluxLibreStep2__TotalPrice">
                                <p>{{ fluxLibreTotalPrice}}
                                </p>
                                <span id="totalPrice">0</span>
                            </div>
                        </section>




FWIW your wireframe does not appear to match your description "all the way in blue" part.  Perhaps clarify what that means - i.e. just the BAR/Lines or the radio buttons also?  It would be best if you have the same element in your wireframe be colored the same as your description not different visual elements.

the way means, the button and the line, i have the example (left one)

I formatted your code however you appear to have actually changed the question with NEW code after accepting an answer.  If you have a NEW issue please ask a NEW question not edit an OLD question.

Adding a NEW event handler inside an event handler it NOT the proper way to do this i.e. const CalculatePrice = () => {   $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {

I reverted the change to the prior version.

@MarkSchultheiss, i want to create a new post with a new version, but i had this message : You can’t post new questions right now
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from your account because most of your questions need improvement or are out of scope for this site. See the Help Center page Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account? to learn more.

Only you can go back and improve all your questions effectively to reduce this question quality pattern. This is a good guide on part of this issue https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and this gives some additional guidance on the matter https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Also if you have an answer posted by someone that does answer the question as asked; even if you answered your own question you can mark it as answered.   IF a closed as duplicate is truly not a duplicate improve question focus and note why it is NOT a duplicate and vote to have it re-opened.

I used a selector to grab all the checked checkboxes.  Then loop through the LIs adding the is-active class when we are between the first and last checked checkbox.


var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(
    '.StepProgress-item input[type="checkbox"]'
);

checkboxes.forEach((checkbox, index) => {
  checkbox.addEventListener("change", function () {
    redrawSteps();
  });
});
  
const redrawSteps = () => {
  // remove existing blue path
  const bluePath = document.querySelectorAll('.StepProgress-item');
  bluePath.forEach(li => li.classList.remove("is-active"));
  // get all the checked checkboxes, so we can find the first and last
  const checked = document.querySelectorAll('.StepProgress-item input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  
  if (checked.length > 1) {
    // get the first and last li that contain a checked checkbox
    const first = checked[0].closest("li");
    const last = checked[checked.length - 1].closest("li");
    let started = false;
    let finished = false;
    
    bluePath.forEach(li => {
      if (li === first) {
        started = true;
      } else if (li === last) {
        finished = true;
      }

      if (started && !finished) {
        li.classList.add("is-active");
      }
    });
  }
};
.StepProgress {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style: none;

    &.inverse {
      flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
    &:before {
      display: inline-block;
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 11px;
      left: 0;
      width: 10px;
      height: 100%;
      border-left: 4px solid #ccc;
    }
  }
  .StepProgress-item {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;

    input[type="checkbox"] {
      appearance: none;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin-right: 10px;
      background-color: $white;
      position: relative;
      top: 6px;
      left: -8px;

      &:checked {
        border: 1px solid  blue ;

        &:before {
          content: "";
          background-color: blue;
        }
      }
      &:before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        width: 12px;
        height: 12px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }
    }

    > label {
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 700;
      padding-top: 5px;

      span {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 400;
      }
    }
    &.subItem {
      margin-left: 40px;

      input[type="checkbox"] {
        &:checked {
          & + label {
            &:before {
              background-color: blue;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      > label {
        position: relative;

        &:before {
          content: "";
          display: inline-block;
          position: absolute;
          left: -70px;
          top: calc(50% + 2px);
          width: 30px;
          height: 4px;
          transform: translateY(-50%);
          background-color: gray;
        }
      }
   
      &.is-active::before {
        content: "";
        left: -40px;
        top: 15px;
        height: calc((100% + 45px) / 2);
        
      }
    }
  }
  .StepProgress-item:not(:last-child) {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .StepProgress-item.is-active:last-of-type &,
  .StepProgress-item.is-active:first-of-type & {
    &::before {
      content: none;
    }
  }
  .StepProgress-item.is-active::before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    /* left: -1px; */
    top: 19px;
    height: calc((100% + 51px) / 2);
    width: 4px;
    background:  blue;
  }

  .StepProgress-item.is-done::before {
    border-left: 2px solid green;
  }
  .StepProgress-item.is-done::after {
    content: "✔";
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid green;
    background-color: green;
  }

  .StepProgress strong {
    display: block;
  }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="FluxLibreStep2__Road">

                        <ul class="StepProgress list-inline">
                           <li class="StepProgress-item ">
                              <input type="checkbox" id="point1" name="flavor" value="point1">
                              <label for="point1">
                                 Point 1
                                 <span class="price"> 12 </span>
                              </label>
                           </li>
                           <li class="StepProgress-item subItem ">
                              <input type="checkbox" id="point2" name="flavor" value="point2">
                              <label for="point2">
                                 Award an entry
                                 <span class="price"> 12 </span>
                              </label>
                           </li>
                           <li class="StepProgress-item">
                              <input type="checkbox" id="point3" name="flavor" value="point3">
                              <label for="point3">
                                 Post a contest
                                 <span class="price"> 15 </span>
                              </label>
                           </li>
                           <li class="StepProgress-item subItem">
                              <input type="checkbox" id="point4" name="flavor" value="point4">
                              <label for="point4">
                                 Handover
                                 <span class="price"> 22 </span>
                              </label>
                           </li>
                           <li class="StepProgress-item">
                              <input type="checkbox" id="point5" name="flavor" value="point5">
                              <label for="point5">
                                 Provide feedback
                                 <span class="price"> 6 </span>
                              </label>
                           </li>
                        </ul> 

                     </div>
                     <p>Selected option: <span id="selectedOption"></span></p>




Thank you so much James, it works as charm, i just have an option to inverse the passages (i added the code above) and when i switch the order of the checkbox is not the same anymore

Aaaaaaaaaah i just added redrawSteps(); in my  siwtch function $("#fluxLibreSwitchCity").click(function () { and that works ! Thank you James :*

Hey @James i made some update on the code above if you have an idea about the issue please !
